# django-oauth2-provider syntax errors inside virtualenv

Tags: django, oauth-2.0

I did a pip install django-oauth2-provider inside my virtualenv with python 3.2, django 1.6, and djangorestframework 2.3.9

I get the following syntax errors:

Running setup.py install for django-oauth2-provider

```
warning: no files found matching '*.txt' under directory 'provider/templates'
warning: no files found matching '*json' under directory 'provider/'
  File "/home/denise/pf-env/lib/python3.2/site-packages/provider/oauth2/tests.py", line 108
    self.assertTrue(escape(u"No 'response_type' supplied.") in response.content)
                                                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

  File "/home/denise/pf-env/lib/python3.2/site-packages/provider/oauth2/forms.py", line 63
    return u' '.join([smart_unicode(val) for val in value]).split(u' ')
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

  File "/home/denise/pf-env/lib/python3.2/site-packages/provider/forms.py", line 54
    except OAuthValidationError, e:
                               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

  File "/home/denise/pf-env/lib/python3.2/site-packages/provider/views.py", line 256
    except OAuthError, e:
                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: In your SO posts, you should describe what you've tried to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the .tox file in the project repository, only Python 2.6 and 2.7 versions are supported. There are also 2 open pull requests to fix support for Django 1.6.

See:
https://github.com/caffeinehit/django-oauth2-provider/blob/master/tox.ini